# how to write an array by using write() in file

Tags: java, file

Here the `fos.write(Arrays.toString(mark[]));` cannot be used. What should I do to write the array values?

```
class Write {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\file program\\hai.txt");
        String name = Streams.readName();
        fos.write(name.getBytes());
        fos.flush();
        //fos.close();
        int[] mark = Streams.readMark();
        fos.write(Arrays.toString(mark[]));
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("data entred");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    }
        catch (IOException e) {
    }
}}
```

**My output:**

[image: My output]

Comment: please add some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fos.write(Arrays.toString(mark[]));` is not correct

remove the **[ ]**

and try instead:

```
 fos.write(Arrays.toString(mark));
```

Comment: `FileOutputStream` does not have a `write` method that accepts a `String`. 4 people don't seem to know that. As for the `[]`, please just vote as typo.